# How do I pass input field values to pdf?

Tags: php, input, tcpdf

I don't know php that much and would like to know how to pass form input values to a pdf (using TCPDF)? What lines of code would I need to add? It can't be that complicated, I've been searching for long but I can't find answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$_POST` or `$_GET` and retrieve them from within your TCPDF class.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm afraid my php skills are too poor.